# TypeScript: is there a way to do const assertions on the array return by Object.values?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is the live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rgb-u860z?file=/src/index.ts

```
enum Keys {
  One = "one",
  Two = "two"
}

const a = Object.values(Keys).map((value, index) => ({
  label: value,
  id: String(index)
})) as const;
```

Here is the error message

> A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum
> members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.

I am not sure what I am missing here since `Object.values` indeed returns an array. Why can't I make const assertion on it

Comment: It should read / be read as: “.. array [literal], or object literal.”

Comment: The "literal" qualifier refers to all of string, number, array and object here.

Comment: you can do `.map(... as const)` which will result in an implicit `const a:{ readonly label: Keys; readonly id: string; }[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't do this is because the left hand side `X` of a const assertion `X as const` has to be a literal value that the TypeScript compiler knows.

So I assume your end goal is that you want to have the full type of A. Without any special stuff you get this:

```
const a: {
    label: Keys;
    id: string;
}[]
```

Now if you want to get this:

```
const a: [
    {
        label: "one";
        id: "0";
    },
    {
        label: "two";
        id: "1";
    }
]
```

This isn't really possible since you're depending on `Object.values` iteration order. Which is defined by ES2015, but typescript types don't "know" about it.

With some simple fancy types you can get to:

```
type EnumEntry<T> = T extends any ? { label: T, id: string } : never;

const a: EnumEntry<Keys>[] = Object.values(Keys).map((value, index) => ({
  label: value,
  id: String(index)
}));
```

```
const a: ({
    label: Keys.One;
    id: string;
} | {
    label: Keys.Two;
    id: string;
})[]
```

But that's the best I think we can do without depending on how typescript orders the types.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly a const assertion, but you could do something like:
`as ReadonlyArray<{label: Keys, id: string}>` instead of `as const`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0sCeBnKBvAUFKB5EwoF4oAiAe1yIBoMoAVAdxIOIBcGi0BfNNAYzMWZQAhkywAjAFbAezAHQA3IQBswwRAAo4SAJSyIQgA7r1ilcApQAliAAmwAB7aCAPijr0mJULHAlALihTVSpMSxsAgGVmACdrAHN1aztHTm0nIWQAJWAhGzIleABBaOiheAAeFC8ff1gERAswgIFYkDiOZwBubj4QRBIlYFklEgShbW60IVkDMEQAC3UARicAelWoAGESCANLQahmSwg8YBKSaLQgA)